# Flow-like functions associated to the solutions of the IVP $x'=f(t,x)\quad x(0)=x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to prove the next result on flow-like functions  for differential equations:

> Let $f$ be a function and suppose that for every $u=(0,x_0)\in \mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}^n$ there is a maximal solution for the IVP 
>   $$x'=f(t,x)\quad x(0)=x_0$$
>   containing $u$, say $\phi(t,x_0)$. Consider the family of functions
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> K_t:\mathbb{R}^n&\to&\mathbb{R}^n\\
> x&\mapsto& K_t(x):=\phi(t,x)
> \end{eqnarray}
>   with $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Then these functions satisfy the following conditions:
>
> 1. $K_0=0$
> 2. $K_{s+t}=K_s\circ K_t$
> 3. The map
>      \begin{eqnarray} K:\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}^n&\to&\mathbb{R}^n\\
>    (t,x)&\mapsto& K_t(x) \end{eqnarray} 
>      is continuous.

Here is my attempt. For the part two I showed that both $\phi(t+s,x_0)$ and $\phi(s,\phi(t,x_0))$ are solutions of the differential equation, so the conclusion follows from the uniqueness of the maximal solutions.

Any hints for the other two items? Specially the first one doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Can you check if the task demands an autonomous ODE? In the non-autonomous case 2) is wrong, the flow also depends on the initial time. Btw., 1.) should have $K_0=Id$.

Comment: No, the ODE is not necessarily autonomous. The condition 1.) says $K_0=0$, but it doesn't seem right. Probably it is as you say. Also the condition 2.) says $K_{s+t}=K_sK_t$. I supposed it means composition, but it might be wrong too.

Comment: For non-autonomous ODE the flow needs to be defined as $x(t)=ϕ(t; t_0,x_0)$ with $ϕ(t_0; t_0,x_0)=x_0$. Then $$ϕ(t+s; t_0,x_0)=ϕ(t; t_0+s, ϕ(t_0+s; t_0,x_0))$$ which looks a little more complicated, even for $t_0=0$. One could define the propagators $K_{t,s}(x)=ϕ(t;s,x)$ where then $K_{t,r}=K_{t,s}\circ K_{s,r}$, but in general these do not depend only on the time difference.